# Твір VS текст - поняття тотожні?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, терміни

Чи можна назвати твір текстом, а текст твором? Наприклад, замовляння від вроків (фольклор) буде текстом чи твором? Геть заплуталася у відмінностях термінів.

У Вікіпедії читаємо:

> [твір](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80) -  багатофункціональне поняття: 1) загальний термін для позначення результату інтелектуальної (аналітико-синтетичної чи еврістичної) діяльності людини (творчої діяльності); 2) позначення того, що зроблене (створене) ким-небудь і реально існує (має форму): виріб (витвір, творіння, утвір), опус тощо; 3) результат інтелектуальної, аналітико-синтетичної чи еврістичної діяльності окремої людини чи групи людей, поданий у формі, що дає змогу його поширення, отримання, зберігання, обробки, відтворення для використання різними засобами, методами, способами, технологіями.
>
> [текст](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82) - це витвір мовленнєвого процесу, [...] який складається із заголовка і ряду особливих одиниць (надфразових єдностей), об'єднаних різними типами лексичного, граматичного, логічного, стилістичного зв'язку, і має певну цілеспрямованість і прагматичну визначеність.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твір і текст це не одне й те саме.

[Твір і текст](http://journlib.univ.kiev.ua/index.php?act=article&article=138)
 (літературознавча позиція):

> Текст і твір - це не одне й те ж. Твір - це продукт мовної діяльності людини, найчастіше закріплений у тексті. Текст - це лише графічно-знакова фіксація твору.

Щодо фольклору, то загальне значення цих термінів наступне.

***(Иванова Т. Г. (Ленинград). Специфика фольклористической текстологии)***:

> **Произведение** как таковое существует в коллективной памяти носителей фольклора. **Текст** же произведения каждым из сказителей при каждом отдельном акте исполнения воссоздается (не создается!) заново. Не зафиксированный с помощью каких-либо технических средств (карандаш и бумага, магнитофон, грампластинка и т. д.) **фольклорный текст**, отзвучав, исчезает, перестает существовать.

Тобто ця дослідниця вважає, щоб можна було сказати про **текст**, зразок фольклору має бути зафіксованим за допомогою технічних засобів.

**Азбелев С.П.( Основные понятия текстологии в применении к фольклорному материалу)** вважає, що існує  2 поняття:

> **текст усний** –це текст такий який він існує в реальному житті фольклору, який зберігається в пам'яті людей [переклад наш] і **фольклорний текст**- текст зафіксований технічними записами, тобто фольклорний запис.

**О. Бріцина ( Дискусійні аспекти визначення поняття "текст" у фольклористиці. Власне текстологічне застосування терміна. Основні текстологічні категорії)** приймає думку Азбелєва С.:

> «У процесі документування, що здійснюється фольклористами, **усний текст** відтворюється власне текстом (текстом запису)».

Отже, **твір** – це те, що живе в пам’яті людей, ( абстрактне поняття);  **текст** – це певний зразок у процесі виконання, або (і) зафіксований за допомогою технічних засобів .
Якщо говорити про замовляння, які побутують в українському фольклорі і «живуть» в пам’яті людей – то замовляння є  **творами**, якщо ж Ви бачите замовляння на папері, чуєте на аудіозаписах, відеозаписах, або просто «наживо», то замовляння є **текстами**.

П.С. Відповідь побудована на положеннях більшості російських дослідників, але, на жаль, українська текстологія почала розвиватися набагато пізніше, ніж російська і багато в чому опирається на здобутки російських колег.